# Nativescript height reset after animation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

While using the Nativescript animate function the element grows in height as expected, but when the animation is over it goes back to the original height.

This is what I tried.

```
this.messages = <StackLayout>args.object;
this.messages.animate({
        height: 400,
        duration: 1000,
        curve: AnimationCurve.linear
      })
```

I also tried multiplating the element .height property itself but it had no effect.

```
this.messages.height += 10;
```

I am testing this on a Iphone X IOS 13.2

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, please share a Playground example.

Comment: Here is the link to the playground. On Android the element won't even grow bigger during the animation. On IOS it will grow then go back to the original  size. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mIEwDg

Comment: Essentially I am trying to have a component off the screen initially and when the user tap a icon it will move up and overlay most of the screen. I am not sure if trying to make the component very large initially and just moving it up is better than, trying to make it gradually grow as it moves.

Comment: The issue is your layout, you have it inside StackLayout, it re-arranges the items on the vertical stack. You should probably use a GridLayout to float the message above ListView.

Comment: Thank you the Grid layout fixed the resizing problem! Do you think it is better to have the component already sized and just translate it up? Or to enlarge it and as it moves up?

Comment: I would say just moving it up will be good, unless it's not fulfilling your expectations.

Comment: Okay thank you so much! is there a way to know what translate actually correlates to? If I want to translate my element from its initial position on the bottom on the screen to a spot 70% up the screen the back to the original position, is there math so that I can do that?

Comment: It's translateX and translateY attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will look into that!